Fixing cracked grout at countertop / backsplash intersection
Ever since we moved in, our kitchen countertops have had a clear line of separation between themselves and the tile backsplash. Is this because they used a grout here or does this look like a caulk that's experienced too much separation?
In either case, I'd like to fix it. What would be the best thing to do here? Should I use a sanded caulk to match the sanded looking texture between the tiles, or just go with plain silicone?
Also, what's the best way to remove the old material? Should I use a utility knife, a grout too, or something else? Obviously I don't want to scratch or mess up either the tiles or the countertop.


Edit:
Editing to provide clarity on why another posted question doesn't completely answer my question. From the comments:
"The question you posted is certainly similar, but I was hoping to get advice on my specific situation. As my question states, I was curious about caulk vs sanded caulk, as well as understanding the best way to remove this. Like my question states, I know a grout saw is used for grout often, but I've also seen utility knives used on some youtube videos. And I'm not entirely sure what the material is either. Sure, it kind of looks like grout, but if you look on the right in the second picture there's a "waviness" to where it's separating. I've seen that with caulk but wasn't sure if that was expected with grout. Knowing what I'm removing might be helpful in removing it and knowing what to replace with. Finally, the gap here is fairly wide. I could imagine someone telling me a sanded caulk is better for such a wide gap, but I don't know that for sure."

The question you posted is certainly similar, but I was hoping to get advice on my specific situation. As my question states, I was curious about caulk vs sanded caulk, as well as understanding the best way to remove this. Like my question states, I know a grout saw is used for grout often, but I've also seen utility knives used on some youtube videos.

And I'm not entirely sure what the material is either. Sure, it kind of looks like grout, but if you look on the right in the second picture there's a "waviness" to where it's separating. I've seen that with caulk but wasn't sure if that was expected with grout. Knowing what I'm removing might be helpful in removing it and knowing what to replace with. Finally, the gap here is fairly wide. I could imagine someone telling me a sanded caulk is better for such a wide gap, but I don't know that for sure.

That's grouted, but it shouldn't be.  You have some movement between the wall and the counter (no way to say which is moving).  The joint should be caulked, not grouted.  Should be a flexible caulk, and if in a wet location (behind sink?) should be waterproof.  Generally this means silicone or polyurethane.

You have sanded grout, so use sanded caulk. It's purely an appearance thing.
The grout separates at its weakest points, hence the zigzag. That doesn't indicate any specific concern.
Use whatever tools you have on had that allow you to gently knock it loose. I'd try a putty knife and a hammer to tap directly toward the wall. Just don't impact the tile glaze. You can chip it.
You could also just caulk the gap and tool the caulk flush with the existing grout (after removing loose bits).

Thanks, isherwood. Appreciate it. I suppose a sanded ceramic tile caulk like this would work: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-Polyblend-11-Snow-White-10-5-oz-Sanded-Ceramic-Tile-Caulk-PC1110S/100678066 ? I'll have to think about the best color match, but it looks like I have quite a few options.

I would think so. If an exact match isn't found, err on the lighter side. Dark will show more in this case.
